# Retrieving a fixed amount of data from a Swift Array

Tags: swift

I have `var toPlotLines:[Int] = [200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 322, 435]` and I want to retrieve the first four `integers` from the `array`. Can I do that without having to loop in `Swift`. I tried this `graphView.graphPoints = toPlotLines[0..<n]` where `graphPoints` is an `empty integer array` but, I keep getting this error:

> Cannot subscript a value of type [int]

Comment: By doing `toPlotLines[0..<n]` you'll return `ArraySlice` of the original array. You can wrap it up into a regular `Array` type.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error message is misleading. The problem is that `toPlotLines[0 ..< n]`
is not an `Array` but an [`ArraySlice`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios//documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_ArraySlice_Structure/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/struct/s:VSs10ArraySlice):

> The Array-like type that represents a sub-sequence of any Array, ContiguousArray, or other ArraySlice.

To create a "real array", use

```
graphView.graphPoints = Array(toPlotLines[0 ..< n])
```

Answer (score 1):

#### From `Array<Int>` to `ArraySlice<Int>`

When you subscript to an `Array`, the type of the returned object is an `ArraySlice`:

```
let toPlotLines = [200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 322, 435] // type: [Int]
let arraySlice = toPlotLines[0 ..< 4] // type: ArraySlice<Int>
```

You can learn more about `ArraySlice` with [ArraySlice Structure Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_ArraySlice_Structure/index.html).

---

#### From `ArraySlice<Int>` to `Array<Int>`

On one hand, `ArraySlice` conforms to `CollectionType` protocol that inherits itself from `SequenceType`. On the other hand, `Array` has an initializer `init(_:)` with the following declaration:

```
init<S : SequenceType where S.Generator.Element == _Buffer.Element>(_ s: S)
```

Therefore, it's possible to get a new `Array` from an `ArraySlice` easily:

```
let toPlotLines = [200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 322, 435]
let arraySlice = toPlotLines[0 ..< 4]
let newArray = Array(arraySlice)
print(newArray) // prints: [200, 300, 400, 500]
```

---

#### From `ArraySlice<Int>` to `Array<String>`

Because `ArraySlice` conforms to `SequenceType`, you can use `map` (or other functional methods like `filter` and `reduce`) on it. Thereby, you are not limited to get an `Array<Int>` from your `ArraySlice<Int>`: you can get an `Array<String>` (or any other array type that would make sense) from your `ArraySlice<Int>`.

```
let toPlotLines = [200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 322, 435]
let arraySlice = toPlotLines[0 ..< 4]
let stringArray = arraySlice.map { String($0) }
print(stringArray) // prints: ["200", "300", "400", "500"]
```